# Enable $RepeatedMsgReduction only for specific log file

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog, syslog

If this were the script for routing messages to log files in rsyslog.conf, is it possible to activate RepeatedMsgReduction only for app_log?

```
if ($syslogfacility-text == "auth") then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/sec_log")
} else if ($msg contains "alarm") then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/alarm_log")
} else {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/app_log")
}
```

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542758/rsyslog-conditional-repeatedmsgreduction/20555451#20555451)
but the solution proposed doesn't work with my rsyslog.conf which uses RainerScript to route messages to logs. No matter in which order or where in conf I place $RepeatedMsgReduction on/off only the last directive is active and for all log files.